# sup of functions on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to prove that $\sup_{t \in [ 0, 1]} | t^m - \delta_1 ( t) | = 1$
where $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\delta_1 ( t) = 1$ if $t = 1$ and $0$
otherwise. I think that the sup is taken over the set $[0,1)$ because $t^m$ is continuous. How does one write a rigorous proof of that. Does taking a sequence $t_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that the supremum of a set is $1$, you must show that

- All values of the set are smaller than $1$ (in your case, this is obvious)
- For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist values in the set which are larger than $1-\varepsilon$

For the second part, see what happens if you take $t = 1-\delta$. Can you find a $\delta$ small enough that $t^m > 1-\varepsilon$?

Comment: Does $\delta< 1-(1-\varepsilon)^{\frac{1}{m}}$ work? Would a Taylor expansion get a simpler $\delta$?

Comment: Why would you do a Taylor expansion for a polynomial?

Comment: I was thinking about something like $(1-\delta)^m\geq 1 -\delta m$.

Comment: Well, if you know that $(1-\delta)^m \geq 1-\delta m$ (this is true for $\delta$ which is small enough, but you must either know where this is shown or be able to show it yourself), then for $\delta < \varepsilon/m$, you have $(1-\delta)^m \geq 1-\varepsilon$ and you're done!.

Comment: For $0<h<1$, $m>\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}h^m=\frac{1-h^m}{1-h}$ and then by substituting $\delta=1-h$, we get $(1-\delta)^m>1-\delta m$.

Answer (score 0):

With your idea:
$$
\left(1-{1\over n}\right)^m>1-\epsilon\qquad{\rm iff}\qquad
1-{1\over n}>\root m\of{1-\epsilon}\qquad{\rm iff}\qquad
n>{1\over 1-\root m\of{1-\epsilon}}.
$$